# Does kendo-ui work with Angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, angular1.6

Can Kendo-ui components be used in a project running AngularJS version 1.6 and is using typescript? Only information I could find on [Kendo's website](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#toc-set-up-the-angular-project) is about AngularJS version 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have few applications using AngularJS 1.6 with Kendo UI.

However, I could not say about TypeScript, as I just used plain JavaScript at that time.

*Not: The only reason I used AngularJS 1.6 at that time was Kendo UI was not production ready for Angular 2 yet, but they now do. I highly suggest you to use Angular 2/4, if possible.*

Comment: It is not possible for me to upgrade to Angular 2/4 at this time as there are other dependent modules which will get affected.

Comment: I see. In a nutshell, Kendo UI is compatible with AngularJS 1.6.

Comment: Not all widgets from the previous generation have a counterpart for Angular2/4, like the Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Kendo UI JS widgets with angular 1.6. Notice that these are not the Angular2/4 components but the previous generation widgets.

You can find their documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui).

I've used them in my project before we moved to Angular2 and I still use some of the previous generation widgets since not all of them have an Angular2 counterpart.